# access a specific property is a nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

As I can access a specific property it is a nested ng-repeat this is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
        {{key}}:{{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

So far so good, I want to do is get the value of a particular property to another action
with that, that is a comparison to something more like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
   <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
        <div ng-if="key.myProperty==1">
           //My Code
        </div>
        <div ng-if="key.miProperty==2">
           //My Code
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My object is:

```
$scope.list = [{id:1,name:"name1",age:"22"},{id:2,name:"name1",age:"25"},{id:2,name:"name1",age:"25"}];
```

I want to get the value of age.

Any suggestions.

Comment: key is a string, shouldn't you use `value.miPropiedad`

Comment: there is no reason for the second `ng-repeat` in this example.

Comment: If you are repeating on item in list, you have access to age with item.age. What is the inner repeat for?

Comment: Hello Claies: Well I have not shown, but according to a value or another will be chosen from a list or other tour that is the reason for which will be checking each of the values

Comment: that doesn't make sense.  Please show the entire code that you are trying to troubleshoot; as written, you are performing a needless iteration over an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you just simply need the age value in the repeat, then you do not need the inner repeat, all you need is

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in list">
    {{item.age}}
 </div>
```

Unless I am missing something here, you can simply just do this. Here's a fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/1298/

So unless you need this to build dynamically off the data, you would just do :

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">
     id: {{item.id}}
     age: {{item.age}}
     name: {{item.name}} 
   </div>
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say with `key.myProperty` because as was mentioned, key is a string. If you want to check if the age is a certain value you can do something like.

```
<div ng-if="key === 'age' && value === '1'">
```

Comment: Thanks ajmajmajma, I finally solved my problem thanks for the help.

Comment: @RodoBautista no problem, glad i could help.